# (window).load preloads site with option to abort

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [PreLoadMe](https://niklausgerber.com/blog/preloadme-a-lightweight-jquery-website-preloader/) to preload simple static website. If loading somehow takes ages, it would be good idea to add link, which could abort(not STOP) loading so that user at least could wait while seeing something.

JS

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('#status').fadeOut();
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    })
```

HTML

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
    <a href="#">Leave the loading, I want to see the site!</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;left:0;
    right:0;bottom:0;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:9999; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
```

I indeed crave for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('#preloader').hide()`?

Comment: I thought of something much complicated... Looks like it works `<a href="#" onclick="$('#preloader').hide()">Hide</a>`
Thanks!

Comment: if you use `delay`, it is better to hide with `queue: false` option. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26571362/947687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind click event to a link you you want to close overlay and hide it on click:

```
$('#preloader').on('click', '.btn-close', function() {
    $('#preloader').hide();
});
```

with improved HTML (it's better to denote close link with some class, like `.btn-close`):

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
    <a href="#" class="btn-close">Leave the loading, I want to see the site!</a>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uj6m1eh6/

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/47br60du/)

```
$('#preloaderHider').click(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut({
        queue: false,
        duration: 'slow'
    });
});
```

Don't forget to set `queue: false` option. Without it when window will be loaded, a click on `#preloaderHider` will have no effect.